# the right way to select a child node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a [jstree](https://www.jstree.com) 3.3.8 tree that looks like this:

[image: tree]

I am trying to upgrade it from version 1.x of jstree. When the tree loads I need to pre-select some child nodes. If I try to open it like this:

```
var tree = $('#mytree')
tree.jstree(true).check_node($('#id_' + id[x]))
```

it doesn't work. After some troubleshooting, I determined that when the tree loads it only loads the root-level items and doesn't even create the child nodes. When the line above runs, there is no node created yet, and nothing happens. I found that if I did this:

```
var tree = $('#mytree')
tree.jstree(true).open_node($('a[group_id=\'' + group_id[x] + '\']'))
tree.jstree(true).check_node($('#id_' + id[x]))
```

I could get it to work by opening the parent node, but it seems like this isn't the "right" way to do it. Is it possible to tell jstree to go ahead and create the child nodes, or even better to create them just for the parents that need to have children pre-selected?